The cocountable topology on any infinite set is not compact?
So, if $E$ is infinite and countable, then the cocountable topology coincides with the discrete topology and $\bigcup_{x \in E} \{x\}$ is an open cover that hasn't got a finite subcover.
If $E$ is not countable, let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an injective sequence of elements of $E$ and let $C_k=\{ x_n \mid n \geq k\}$; then $E= \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}E-C_k$ that hasn't got any subcover; since if that were the case, as $E-C_1 \subset E-C_2 \subset \dots$ is a nested sequence, we'd have that $E-C_{m}$ would cover $E$ but $x_m \notin E-C_m$. Is this procedure correct?

What do you mean by “coincides with the discrete topology”?

It's equivalent

Your proof is correct. I'll note that you don't need a special case for when $E$ is countable; your proof works in general for any infinite set.
